# How to leave (interrupt) the waitpid() function?

Tags: c, shell, unix, wait, waitpid

Currently I am programming a shell and I use the `waitpid()` function for my children processes.

I also installed a signal handler so I can trap the SIGINT (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) signal.

So what I want now is when someone presses the SIGINT (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) signal it should leave the `waitpid()` functions and keep going as usually.

I am looking for a function who can help me about that.

Comment: Don’t set SA_RESTART in the flags when you call `sigaction()`.

Comment: ... `sigaction()` is preferred over using `signal()` to install a signal handler.

Comment: Consider also handling the `SIGCHLD` signal, see [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) & [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html)

Answer (score 0):

Install your signal handler *without* the `SA_RESTART` flag:

```
void handler( int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *arg )
{
    ...
}

...

struct sigaction newact;
memset( &newact, 0, sizeof( newact ) );
sigemptyset( &newact.sa_mask );
newact.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;  // note that **lack** of SA_RESTART
newact.sa_siginfo = handler;

sigaction( SIGINT, &newact, NULL );
```

You'll have to add error checking to that, and note that you will now have to handle interrupted calls in your code.

Comment: OT: I'd use `struct sigaction newact = {0};` instead of calling `memset()`.

Comment: @alk I've been around too long... :-)

Comment: Also I doubt that explicitly emptying `sa_mask` is necessary. Also^2 why do you set `SA_SIGINFO` for a handler which actually does nothing. So assuming `void handler(int sig);` then the short version could be `{ sigaction(SIGINT, (struct sigaction){handler}, NULL); }` :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I dont understand what you calling, do you have a reference or something like that?

Comment: @alk I tend to be paranoid about making sure all my variables are properly initialized - a defensive coding measure against the bugs I'm going to put in (two kinds of programmers: those who create bugs, and liars).  As far as `SA_SIGINFO`, we don't know what he OP's signal handler does, so I provided an example of the more complex usage.

Answer (score 0):

A process blocking on [`waitpid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) would return on reception of a signal and set `errno` to `EINTR`.

For this to work the signal handler my not have been installed with the option `SA_RESTART`.

To install a signal handle without setting the option `SA_RESTART` the prefered function is [`sigaction()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html).

```
void handle(int sig)
{
  /* Do nothing. */
}

int main(void)
{
  sigaction(SIGINT, (struct sigaction){handler}, NULL);

  /* fork and bla ... */

  if (-1 == waitpid(..., /*no WNOHANG here */))
  {
    if (EINTR == errno)
    {
      /* process received signal */
      ...
```